# Reference needed

Tags: rt.representation-theory

I would like to know that whether this paper " Groups having three complex irreducible character degrees by Thomas Noritzsch" has a corrigendum?

Comment: Emily, is it possible to send an email to the author? That would be the surest way to know the answer to your question.


Answer (score 6, accepted):

According with MathSciNet and Zentralblatt, it seems that there is no author's corrigendum for this paper. However, a corrected version of his results can be found in the following paper:

M. Lewis - J. Riedl: 
Affine semi-linear groups with three irreducible character degrees, 
J. Algebra 246 (2001), no. 2, 708–720.

Answer (score 1):

In the article

Liang, Qian, Shi, Finite groups whose all irreducible character degrees
are Hall-numbers,Journal of Algebra, {\bf 307}(2007), 695–703

the authors referred to the Noritzsch's paper but didn't mention any corrigendum. Thus I think it don't exists.